# What happens to H2 database cache on a system crash?

Tags: java, database, caching, netbeans, h2

I really had a bad experience today. I applied some batch SQL scripts through Netbeans IDE to my H2 database (which is running in TCP mode). After 5 hours of work, the database connection in Netbeans IDE suddenly freezed... Subsequently I restarted the server (on which the H2 database is running) and then I realized that all changes of the last 5 hours were not applied or somehow rolled back...

My conclusion is, that the changes were only in the cache and not flushed to the database, since the results were at any one time visible when queried after each SQL script.

Therefore, what happens to the database cache in the case of a system failure ? Gone ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The cache is gone in the event of a system failure. You must not have committed the transaction. The only guarantee then is that it must rollback (since it wasn't committed and the client has disconnected).

If it had been committed and subsequently crashed (before flushing) then it would have been possible for the server to still recover based on some combination of commit/transaction log and internal metadata.

Comment: Thanks Elliott for the information. Somehow my transactions were not correctly committed. It now worked for the second time.